# Passing checkbox values to database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, checkbox, meteor

I find checkboxes a powerful tool but I have a hard time wrapping my head around them. I want customers to specify which kind of kitchen they like (fast food, italian, sushi, ..). Later I want to ask restaurants what kitchens they offer and based on the result I want to match customers and restaurants. I thought it would be nice to save all the choices in a kitchen array[]. Is that a good way to go about it or do you usually save each choice as an individual variable? 
My html looks like this:

```
<template name="hello">
    <form class="main form page">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" </label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label> <input  name="kitchen" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" id="italian"> italian</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label> <input name="kitchen" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" id="sushi"> sushi </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input name="kitchen" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" id="fastfood"> fast food </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

The problem is that I don't know the most effective way in which to store the data in the mongo database.

I am working in meteor. So I have to create a template event:

```
Template.hello.events({
'submit form': function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

Now I need to get all the results to the database. Where kitchens is the variable that should be added to the Checkbox collection.

```
var kitchens = {
 fastfood: $(e.target).find('[name=fastfood]').val(),
 sushi: $(e.target).find('[name=sushi]').val(),
 italian: $(e.target).find('[name=italian]').val(),
};

kitchens._id = Checkbox.insert(kitchens);
console.log("added to database");
```

This code will send data to the database and an id is created but I can't see if the checkbox was checked or not. I found the below code to translate the check to a "Yes" or "No" but I don't know how to integrate this into my code:

```
function kitchensChecked(id) {
var X = document.getElementById(id);
if (X.checked == true) {
 X.value = "YES";
} else {
X.value = "NO";
};
```

Could you help me to integrate this code or show me a smoother way to save the checkbox results to the Checkbox collection?

Comment: Is there any way I can get the checkbox results to pass through the check method (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check), without getting a match error? With both solutions it always gives me a match error, no matter whether I tell it to expect a string, an array or undefined. @vinayakj

Answer (score 2):

This is how I deal with checkboxes in my app. I'd remove the `id` field and instead have a `value` field on the checkboxes:

```
<input name="kitchen[]" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" value="italian">
<input name="kitchen[]" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" value="sushi">
<input name="kitchen[]" type="checkbox" class="kitchen" value="fastfood">
```

Then use the [`pcel:serialize`](https://atmospherejs.com/pcel/serialize) package to easily retrieve checked items:

```
var formObject = $('form.main').serializeJSON();
var checkedItems = formObject.kitchen; // an array containing the checked values
```

Comment: `if(Meteor.isClient) {
   Template.kitchen.events({
  'submit form': function() {
   
    var formObject  = $('#kitchen').serializeJSON();
    var checkboxs = formObject.kitchen;
   
  checkboxs._id = Checkboxs.insert(checkboxs);
 
}
});
}` 

with: `Checkboxs = new Mongo.Collection('checkboxs');`
This code works fine. Thank you for the tip with the package!

Answer (score 1):

There is css selector called `:checked` which filters the selection and return only checked inputs.

```
var kitchens = {
 fastfood: $(e.target).find('#fastfood:checked').val(),
 sushi: $(e.target).find('#sushi:checked').val(),
 italian: $(e.target).find('#italian:checked').val()
};
```