# Updating MongoDB with checkbox information

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I'm learning Node.js and Express and using it to make a simple web app that conducts CRUD operations on a mongoDB database. I can successfully insert information into the database and update it however I cannot seem to figure out how to update checkbox information. Note I looked at [Passing checkbox values to database using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625341/passing-checkbox-values-to-database-using-javascript) and it didn't help since it's in meteor.js

In my EJS file. This is the information the user has to insert in order to update a matching entry in the database. I've omitted some elements of the form for the sake of brevity.

```
<div id="editForm" hidden>
    Enter name of the entry you want to edit?<input type="text" placeholder="full name" id="editItem" name="editItem" required><br>
    Full Name<input type="text" placeholder="full name" id="fullName" name="name" required><br>
   Age <input type="number" name="age" min="18" max="95" id="age" required><br>
    Programming Languages <br> <input type="checkbox" class="p_languages2" name="p_languages2" value="Java" required>Java
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_languages2" class="p_languages2" value="C++">C++
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_languages2" class="p_languages2" value="Python">Python
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_languages2" class="p_languages2" value="Ruby">Ruby
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_languages2" class="Jp_languages2" value="JavaScript">JavaScript<br>
    Available to start work? <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" required><br>
    Life Motto? <input type="text" placeholder="motto" id="motto" name="motto" required><br> 
    <button onClick='putRequest()' type="submit" id="editEntry">Submit</button>
   </div>

function putRequest() {
    fetch('/view', {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'editedItem': document.getElementById("editItem").value,
          'name': document.getElementById("fullName").value,
          'age': document.getElementById("age").value,
          //how can I extract the checkboxes?
          'start_date': document.getElementById("start_date").value,
          'motto': document.getElementById("motto").value
        })
     })

    window.location.reload(true);
```

And here's my put request for extra information. Note that "p_languages": req.body.p_languages is just a placeholder, I know it doesn't work.

```
app.put('/view', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Put is working!");
    db.collection('jobs').findAndModify(
         {"name": req.body.editedItem },
         {},
         {$set: 
            { "name": req.body.name , "job_title": req.body.job_title, "gender": req.body.gender,
            "p_languages": req.body.p_languages, "age": req.body.age, "start_date": req.body.start_date,"motto": req.body.motto }
         },
         {},
         function(err, object) {
             if (err){
                 console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
             }else{
                 console.log("Update complete");
             }
         })


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to all checkboxes by `name` attribute like this, 
`var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("p_languages2");`. This will return array checkboxes with `p_languages2`. Now you just need to iterate over this array and get the `value` of all the checkboxes which are checked `checkboxes[i].checked` and store that values in an array and update that array on server. [Refer to this plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/EfCvOq8g2s1aGJtFLsQa/).